# Scrollable view on apple watch

Tags: cocoa, swift, apple-watch

Any ideas how to create a view on the apple watch where overflowing content can be panned up, down, left, right (kinda like maps)

The view would need to contain standard UI elements such as buttons etc

Comment: you need to show us what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

No such element exists in WatchKit.

Comment: Apple releases whatever they want to release when they want to release. Also you should accept his answer, which is correct.